# Javascript Regex, Removing unclosed tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for javascript regex solution to remove unclosed tags for example:

```
<div></div><span>
```

As you can see i want to remove the `<span>` element, I know it's a bad idea to use regex on markup but it's required for my project, This is the regex pattern i made but it didn't work:

```
/<([a-z]+?)>([\s\S]*?)(?!<\/\1>)/g
```

I'm using javascript replace to replace all matches with `""`, What i try with my pattern is to match **only** unclosed tags, About the pattern:

1. `[a-z]` i know html tags can contain `=,",etc`, I'm looking for simple pattern that i can play and edit so i started with `[a-z]`
2. I used `!?` to reject matches for closing tags.

I know my pattern isn't working, If anyone have an idea i will be very thankful.

**Edit:**

I'm aware that there may be recursion, If this is the case i want to remove all the recursion tree, I only want to keep 1 level of html for example:

```
<div><span></span></div><p></p>
```

So if the next tag after the `<div>` is not `</div>` remove it.

Comment: Seriously, it is impossible to make that with a full regex solution in Javascript, since Javascript regex doesn't have a recursion feature (the only way to deal with nested tags, except the stack system in .net)

Comment: So, just making sure I understand, `<div><span></span></div><p></p>`, which is perfectly valid html, you want to make that `<div></div><p></p>` ?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep 1 level of html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/17300

Comment: I used this html parser script for cleaning up user entered WYSIWYG markup. It works pretty well for my purpose but only handles HTML4 tags. The regular expressions in John's script could be helpful for others looking to do some Javascript DOM parsing.  http://ejohn.org/apps/htmlparser/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, lets see what OP said:

- I know it's a bad idea to use regex on markup but it's required for my project.
- I only want to keep 1 level of html

This can be achieved.

You were on the right track. However you shouldn't have used `!?` to reject matches for closing tags. You want to accept them. This way the match will not accept unclosed tags which is our goal after all.

Now, your regex will look like this.

```
/<([a-z]+?)>([\s\S]*?)(<\/\1>)/g
```

We can remove the second and third brackets as they are not necessary:

```
/<([a-z]+?)>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/g
```

If we test this regex on the provided code will will get the following:

```
"<div><span></span></div><p></p>".match(/<([a-z]+?)>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/g)
["<div><span></span></div>", "<p></p>"]
```

It seems that our regex matches TOO MUCH symbols. We must break the match at the "<" symbol as it denotes new tag. The [^<] means "any character but "<".

```
"<div><span></span></div><p></p>".match(/<([a-z]+?)>[^<]*?<\/\1>/g)
["<span></span>", "<p></p>"]
```

Finally we can just join the matched results.

```
"<div><span></span></div><p></p>".match(/<([a-z]+?)>[^<]*?<\/\1>/g).join("")
"<span></span><p></p>"
```

Wohoooo. I will leave the first part of regex to you as it was not part of the question. I hope this was helpful. I am open for further questions.